# Find the area of region ABC below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Through the vertices A and C of a triangle rectangle ABC. two circles are drawn
tangents to the legs which intercept at points $D$ and $F$, if : $BF = 4$ ;
calculate the area of region ABC.(Answer:$8$)

Not being able to understand what the figure of the question would be like... Would anyone be able to show how it would look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is given that $\angle ABC=90^\circ$. The only way that a circle can be tangent to both leg $AB$ and leg $BC$ is if those legs each lie on a tangent to the circle, as in the diagram.

[image]

Can you see how the conclusion as to the area of the triangle follows?

Comment: thanks for help, so, the two circles are coincidents?

Comment: Yes, since only one circle satisfies the conditions, the one you see.

Comment: grattude for clarification